# Mongo insert in many-many relations

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have many-many relation created in Mongo collection. I assume there's possibility of large update of relations, by POST request, containing array of new connections.

Connection is defined in following way:

```
Id: ObjectId,
Object1Id: string,
Object2Id: string (ObjectId looking)
```

How, using MongoDB driver for C# can I verify if relation already exists, and if so, this should be skipped, either way added (Id should be generated on fly - during insert), or if relation was removed (i.e. is not found in POST body) - removed from the database? POST might not have Id value.
I have an idea how to do it - one by one, but it looks that it might be a bit overkill, causing blocking Mongo (multiple requests). Is there any better way how to solve such an issue, using possibly smallest number of Mongo requests/queries?

UPDATE:

Collection:

```
{
    _id: ObjId(1),
    object1Id: 1a,
    object2Id: 2a
},
{
    _id: ObjId(2),
    object1Id: 1b,
    object2Id: 2b
},
{
    _id: ObjId(3),
    object1Id: 1a,
    object2Id: 2d
},
```

POST body:

```
[{
    object1Id: 1a,
    object2Id: 2a
},
{
    object1Id: 1a,
    object2Id: 2b
},
{
    object1Id: 1a,
    object2Id: 2c
}]
```

What I forgot to mention - there is perspective of checking - it can be checked from specific obj1 or obj2 perspective
If request done from object1 perspective it tries to match all objects where object1Id is part of request URL, and depending if:

- object stays in collection (request pair 1a, 2a) - nothing is done
- object is removed (collection pair 1a, 2d is missing in request) - it is removed from collection
- pair is added (pairs 1a,2b; 1a,2c in request) - they are added to collection.
- pair (1b, 2b) stays in collection - object1Id is different than request one.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question better. An example would help understand better.

Comment: @raga I updated an issue with examples

Comment: What if we delete all objects where object1Id==1a and then insert the objects in the POST request. 2 calls to db.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're intending to do.  If each element in the post array is an update, you could use a bulk operation to send them all at once.

Comment: @raga I was thinking abouth something like this but I was wondering if there's some simpler solution.

Comment: @Joe there's hard what will be exactly in the array - it could be new items, existing or no previously existing items, i.e. that already existing should be removed.